# Building package structure with child-/sub-packages

Tags: go, package

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in Go. I'm designing it in such a way that I can build a command-line interface first and easily swap in a GUI interface. The project location is `$GOPATH/src/gocalc` (all paths hereafter are relative to the project location). The command-line interface logic is stored in a file `gocalc.go`. The calculator logic is stored in files `calcfns/calcfns.go` and `operations/operations.go`. All files have package names identical to their filename (sans extension) except the main program, `gocalc.go`, which is in the `package main`

`calcfns.go` imports `operations.go` via `import "gocalc/operations"`; `gocalc.go` imports `calcfns.go` via `import "gocalc/calcfns"`

To summarize:

- `$GOPATH/src/gocalc/`

  - `gocalc.go`

    - `package main`
    - `import "gocalc/calcfns"`
  - `calcfns/`

    - `calcfns.go`

      - `package calcfns`
      - `import "gocalc/operations"`
  - `operations/`

    - `operations.go`

      - `package operations`

When I try to `go build operations` (from the project dir), I get the response: `can't load package: package operations: import "operations": cannot find package`
When I try `go build gocalc/operations`, I get `can't load package: package gocalc/operations: import "gocalc/operations": cannot find package`
When I try `go build operations/operations.go`, it compiles fine

When I try to `go build calcfns` or `go build gocalc/calcfns`, I get `can't load package...` messages, similar to those in operations; however, when I try to build `calcfns/calcfns.go` it chokes on the import statement: `import "gocalc/operations": cannot find package`

Finally, when I try `go build .` from the project dir, it chokes similar to the previous paragraph: `import "gocalc/calcfns": cannot find package`

How should I structure my child packages and/or import statements in such a way that `go build` won't fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stupidly, I forgot to export my GOPATH variable, so `go env` displayed `""` for `GOPATH`. (thanks to jnml for suggesting to print `go env`; +1).

After doing this (and moving the main program to its own folder `{project-dir}/gocalc/gocalc.go`), I could build/install the program via `go install gocalc/gocalc`.

Moral of the story, make sure you type `export GOPATH=...` instead of just `GOPATH=...` when setting your $GOPATH environment variable

Answer (score 1):

Please try to also add output of `$ go env` to provide more clues. Otherwise both the directories structure and (the **shown**) import statements looks OK.

However the sentence

> When I try to go build operations (from the project dir), I get the response: can't load package: package operations: import "operations": cannot find package

sounds strange. It seems to suggest you have

```
package operations

import "operations"
```

in 'operations.go', which would be the culprit then...?

Comment: No, `operations` wasn't trying to import itself. ;) But your `go env` did show me that I used `GOPATH=$HOME/Projects/Go` instead of `export GOPATH=$HOME/Projects/Go`, which was the real culprit. Interestingly, `echo $GOPATH` still produced "`[abs path to ~]/Projects/Go`"; however, `go env` showed `GOPATH=""` or some such. Thanks for the suggestion. +1

Answer (score -1):

## Very easy:

Lets say I have a project/app named: `golang-playground`

1. Put your root dir under `GOPATH/src/`, in my case `GOPATH=~/go/src` (run command `go env` to get your `GOPATH`). so complete path for my app is `~/go/src/golang-playground`
   [image]
2. Lets say you want to use function `Index()` inside of file: `router.go` from my `main.go` file (which of course is on root dir). so in main.go:

   ```
   import (
       ...
       "golang-playground/router"
   )

   func main() {
       foo.Bar("/", router.Index) // Notice caps means its public outside of file
   }
   ```